# Volume of a solid of revolution around y axes

Tags: calculus, solid-geometry

The problem is to find the minimum volume for the solid of revolution around y axes given by the curve

$f(x)=-8ax^2+a+\frac{3}{4}$

My first idea was to find what is the parameter a that minimizes the area in the first quadrant given by integral

$\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{a+3/4}{8a}}}f(x) dx$

So then the volume of the solid of revolution given by this curve would be minimum. The problem is that my answer doesnt match with the reference =(

Comment: What is your answer, how did you get it, and what is the given answer?

Comment: Are you assuming only for $y \geq 0$? You need to minimise $\int_{0}^{a+3/4} \pi (f^{-1}(y))^{2}\, dy$, which is the volume of revolution about the $y$-axis. This is a different problem than minimising area.

Comment: By the way, the answer that I got was $a=\frac34$.

Answer (score 0):

$$V=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}2\pi x\,f(x)dx$$
where $f(x)=\frac{4a+3}{4}-8ax^2$ where $a\geq 0$, $x_1=0$ and $x_2=\sqrt{\frac{4a+3}{32a}}$ which is the positive $x$-intercept. Then,
$$V=\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{4a+3}{32a}}}2\pi x(\frac{4a+3}{4}-8ax^2)dx=\frac{(4a+3)^2}{256a}\pi.$$
Minumum volume occurs when $\frac{dV}{da}=0$. The positive solution is $a=\frac34$.